# DVD's still not working

Tags: dvd

Have installed the libraries suggested for getting encrypted DVD's to play but its still not happening. When I typed in

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

the following replied

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
ubuntu-restricted-extras is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  sbsigntool libnumber-compare-perl linux-image-3.11.0-18-generic execstack
  gir1.2-timezonemap-1.0 libipc-run-perl realpath efibootmgr libnet-ip-perl
  squashfs-tools libnet-dns-perl moreutils libdmraid1.0.0.rc16
  libdebconfclient0 libdate-calc-xs-perl kpartx-boot libfile-find-rule-perl
  linux-headers-3.11.0-18-generic libio-pty-perl libwayland-ltss-server0
  linux-generic-lts-saucy user-setup kpartx libelfg0 python-webkit rdate
  linux-headers-3.11.0-18 acpidump libdebian-installer4 read-edid
  libxrandr-ltss2 btrfs-tools liblzo2-2 libdate-calc-perl apt-clone
  localechooser-data libcarp-clan-perl libtext-glob-perl iasl dh-modaliases
  python-dmidecode archdetect-deb libwayland-ltss-client0 dmraid python-pyicu
  cpuid libdigest-hmac-perl libbit-vector-perl pnputils libllvm3.3
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

I try to remove and get

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

How do I reply to this and should I be removing these files anyway (ie could they be stopping the DVD's from working?)

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: version  12.04.5

Comment: Did you try VLC?

Comment: yes, it reads the title but when tries to play it keeps  stopping like its stuck.  The computer plays audio cd's ok so don't think its that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are root, a permission error can happen when another process opened that file. You can check it with *fuser*, e.g.

```
sudo fuser -a /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Comment: How do I rectify a permission error? and if I do should I autoremove those files it suggested?

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot help in this question without an output of fuser command. If there is no other process which is locking this file, you should investigate further.

Comment: I didn't realize. When I type in the fuser command the following appears /var/lib/dpkg/lock: